# Multiple SQL query IN OPERATOR

Tags: mysql

I tried to statements

```
SELECT s.*
FROM status s
WHERE s.reg IN (Select reg from sdel) OR
      s.reg IN (Select reg from ddel);
```

The above mentioned statement works out but when I tried the below mentioned statement, it didn't extract any results for me.

```
 SELECT s.*
    FROM status s
    WHERE s.reg IN (Select reg,pic from sdel where sdel.reg = status.reg) OR
          s.reg IN (Select reg,pic from ddel where ddel.reg = status.reg) OR
          s.reg IN (Select reg,pic from gdel where gdel.reg = status.reg) OR
          s.reg IN (Select reg,pic from ip where ip.reg = status.reg);
```

Comment: The arguments for the IN should be values rather than selects, or a single select. This would be better done using a join between status and sdel and ddel.

Comment: Can you show sample data of the tables and what your expected output is?

Comment: You should not edit your question after it has been answered, because that can invalidate answers.  Just ask another question.  In your case, however, just remove `pic` from the subqueries.

Answer (score 1):

Do this with two `in` expressions:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM status s
WHERE s.reg IN (Select reg from sdel) OR
      s.reg IN (Select reg from ddel);
```

You can also use `UNION ALL` for one query.  But two separate queries give more opportunity for optimization.

Answer (score 0):

In your second query you extract both the attributes `reg` and `pic` and the compare with the only attribute `reg`, so the result is always false.

If you need to compare only `reg`, then remove `pic` from the internal select clause, like in:

```
$res=mysql_query("SELECT s.*
    FROM status s
    WHERE s.reg IN (Select reg from sdel where sdel.reg = status.reg) OR
          s.reg IN (Select reg from ddel where ddel.reg = status.reg) OR
          s.reg IN (Select reg from gdel where gdel.reg = status.reg) OR
          s.reg IN (Select reg from ip where ip.reg = status.reg);");
```

Comment: but i want to extract picture as well

Comment: You are doing select s.* from status s in the outer query. Is the picture present in relation status? or only in the relations sdel, ddel, gdel, ip?

Comment: s.* contains status and pics are present in sdel , ddel , gdel and ip and i want to extract from those tables